# Netscript service - Linux - what does it do on bootup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

I used systemd-bootchart to examine delays to booting my Ubuntu 18.04 system.

The longest was by netscript, for 10.5 seconds, of 20.5 seconds in total.

What does netscript do and how does it work? Will leaving it off affect networking services in any way?

When I disabled it on boot-up, the time fell by that same amount, and as far as I can see, the networking and the firewall are completely unaffected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Netscript**](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/netscript-2.4/netscript.8.en.html) seems to be some wrapper for iptables/ifconfig configuration, QoS configuration in particular. It is used to configure either network interfaces or the iptables firewall. So if all of your configurations are already saved and persistent (through boot), you don't really need it.

> This manual page documents briefly the netscript command from the netscript router/firewall network configuration package.
>   This command is used to configure/reconfigure the interface configuration, ipchains filter setup, and ip route service ( QoS ) setup that are configured in netscript's configuration files. It can manipulate individual interfaces, and reconfigure the iptables filter contents and firewall setup, or reconfigure the QoS setup.

On Debian 9 Stretch it is not installed by default, so I believe you should be absolutely free not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

It dosen't seem to be installed by default - least on my ubuntu 18.04 systems. The [Manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/netscript-2.4/netscript.8.en.html) suggests its a package for 'easier' firewall/router management, and checking with apt confirms it

```
geek@heckate_router:~$ apt search netscript
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
netscript-2.4/bionic 5.5.3 all
  Linux 2.4/2.6/3.x router/firewall/VM host network config system.
```

I run a router/firewall on linux without it so it should be fine to disable. The newfangled network configuration system that ubuntu uses now - netplan dosen't seem to have it as a dependancy either. Its worth doing a simulated uninstall `apt-get uninstall -s netscript` to work out what actually relies on this.